# How to say "faire un rot" in a slang way?

Tags: argot

I am looking for expressions that can be used to say something like I want to burp, or did you burp.

I find saying faire un rot is not slang enough.

Comment: **Roter** is quicker, though closely related. It is also well known even among the deepest and lowest French-speaking societies, so you shouldn't worry about it being too fancy or elegant.

Comment: To add to @Feelew's comment, I'd say posh people do not say *roter* they say *éructer*.  *Roter* is the word you use for a baby,  a French parent *fait faire son rot à son bébé* when an English parent  "burps their baby".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Roter* is  the word you are looking for, even if it is not slang and only colloquial. It is not the word you would use in good company, the posh word to use when you eat out with your boss or with the Queen instead of with pals is *éructer*.

*Faire un rot* can also be used although it is more of a phrase that will be used for babies. *Bébé a fait son rot*... (Baby has burped)